# Disable/Enable AD user account from CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory

How can I enable or disable an AD user account from a csv based on an entry. If the status for both say Active, only one account gets enabled instead of both. Same for the disabled status
CSV file:

```
Samaccountname,Status
john.doe,Active
jane.doe,Disabled
```

What I have so far:

```
Import-CSV -Path c:\folder\adaccounts.csv

ForEach ($User in $Users)
{
    IF ($User.Status -contains "Disabled")
    {
        Get-ADUser -Identity $user.samaccountname | Disable-ADAccount
    }
    elseif ($User.Status -contains "Active")
    {
        Get-ADUser -Identity $user.samaccountname | Enable-ADAccount
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your script you are importing the CSV but it doesn't look like you have assigned it to a variable for your foreach loop
if you assign it to the `$Users` variable like below, the rest of the script should then go through your CSV as expected.

```
$Users = Import-Csv -Path c:\folder\adaccounts.csv
```

Comment: Whoops. I actually forgot to include it in this post. It is on the script though.

Comment: Is the variable you have assigned called `$User` or `$Users` I made a typo in my reply and according to the rest of the script it should be `$Users`

Answer (score 0):

`-Contains` is an operator to test if something can be found in an array of things, not for testing if a string is equal or not to another string.

I would revise your code like this:

```
Import-CSV -Path 'c:\folder\adaccounts.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    # test if a user with that SamAccountName can be found
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($_.Samaccountname)'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($user) {
        # set Enabled if Status is not 'Disabled'
        $user | Set-ADUser -Enabled ($_.Status -ne 'Disabled')
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "User $($_.Samaccountname) does not exist" 
    }
}
```